# How to add ACF radio button field on front-end of Single-Post Page Template?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a WP theme that's used for food ordering and want to add a functionality that's used for calling a waiter service and for that I want to add ACF radio button field on a Restaurant Menu(single-post) page's front-end so that user can select their choices and submit it. I've searched about it as well and find some solutions but it couldn't work in that way.

I'm calling ACF radio button values using php and replace it HTML radio button markup but the ACF radio button field values couldn't call on front-end.Below is my code for calling ACF radio button field values, please have a look on it and provide a relevant solution on it.

```
<?php
    $radio_button_field = get_field('waiter_service');
    if( $radio_button_field ) {
        echo '<form action="" method="post">';
        echo '<label>' . $radio_button_field['label'] . '</label><br />';
        $choices = $radio_button_field['choices'];
        foreach( $choices as $value => $label ) {
            echo '<input type="radio" name="waiter_service" value="' . $value . '"';
            if( get_field('waiter_service') == $value ) {
                echo ' checked="checked"';
            }
            echo ' />' . $label . '<br />';
        }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" />';
        echo '</form>';
    }

    if( isset($_POST['submit_form']) ) {
        $field_value = $_POST['waiter_service'];
        update_field('waiter_service', $field_value);
    }
?>
```

Comment: So where exactly did you put this code? _"but the ACF radio button field values couldn't call on front-end"_ - and "call" is supposed to mean what now, exactly?

Comment: @CBore I've added this code in my single-restaurant.php template and by writing "call" here means that the field values couldn't show on front-end of single-restaurant.php

Comment: And what have you done to debug this, so far? Start by verifying that `$radio_button_field` contains what you think it should, using `var_dump`.

Comment: Both `get_field` and `update_field` will be using the current post id by default. But you want to store an _individual_ choice for each _user_ of your site, do you not?